# Spark Scala: Access data inside struct which is inside of an array

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, aws-glue

The schema looks like this

```
root
|-- orderitemlist: array (nullable = true)
| |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
| | |-- internal-material-code: string (nullable = true)
| | |-- lot-number: string (nullable = true)
| | |-- packaging-item-code: string (nullable = true)
| | |-- packaging-item-code-type: string (nullable = true)
```

how do I access the values for `internal-material-code` and `lot-number`

on creating the dataframe I do this

```
df.withColumn("internalmaterialcode", col("orderitemlist")(0).getItem("internal-material-code"))
```

also

```
df.withColumn("internalmaterialcode", col("orderitemlist")(0)("internal-material-code"))
```

also as follows

```
df.withColumn("orderitemlistarray", explode(col("orderitemlist"))) 
.withColumn("internalmaterialcode", col("orderitemlistarray").getItem("internal-material-code"))
```

also as follows

```
df.withColumn("orderitemlistarray", explode(col("orderitemlist"))) 
.withColumn("internalmaterialcode", col("orderitemlistarray.internal-material-code"))
```

but it gives out `null`

I have seen similar looking schemas on stackoverflow questions but none of the answers were useful for me. Could someone answer it or direct me to the correct place.

Comment: You're looking for `explode`.  Give that a google, lots of info out there.

Comment: I tried it as follows
        `.withColumn("orderitemlistarray", explode(col("orderitemlist")))
        .withColumn("internalmaterialcode", col("orderitemlistarray").getItem("internal-material-code"))`
also as follows

`.withColumn("orderitemlistarray", explode(col("orderitemlist")))
        .withColumn("internalmaterialcode", col("orderitemlistarray.internal-material-code"))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After `explode`, `select` the newly created column and it will gives all the data from `struct fields`.

**`Example:`**

```
val va="""{
    "orderitemlist": [{
        "internal-material-code": "123",
        "lot-number": "vv",
        "packaging-item-code": "pp",
        "packaging-item-code-type": "ll"
    },{
        "internal-material-code": "234",
        "lot-number": "vv",
        "packaging-item-code": "pp",
        "packaging-item-code-type": "ll"
    }]
}"""

val df=spark.read.json(Seq(va).toDS).toDF

df.withColumn("arr",explode(col("orderitemlist"))).select("arr.*").show()
```

**`Result:`**

```
+----------------------+----------+-------------------+------------------------+
|internal-material-code|lot-number|packaging-item-code|packaging-item-code-type|
+----------------------+----------+-------------------+------------------------+
|                   123|        vv|                 pp|                      ll|
|                   234|        vv|                 pp|                      ll|
+----------------------+----------+-------------------+------------------------+
```

Now you will get all the columns from struct inside array..!!

Comment: I'm getting this error - `org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve 'explode(value)' due to data type mismatch: input to function explode should be array or map type, not struct`. I tried this ```df.withColumn("arr",explode(col("value"))).select("arr.*").show()``` Can you please help me?

Comment: I just fixed it by converting it - `df.withColumn("arr",explode(array(col("value")))).select("arr.*").show(false)`

Answer (score 1):

I went through the code block shared by you & it is working fine. Please go through my work here(as an extension to the earlier solution):

```
>>>df.withColumn("ves", $"orderitemlist.lot-number").show
+--------------------+--------+
|       orderitemlist|     ves|
+--------------------+--------+
|[[123, vv, pp, ll...|[vv, vv]|
+--------------------+--------+

>>>df.withColumn("vew", $"orderitemlist".getItem("lot-number")).show
+--------------------+--------+
|       orderitemlist|     vew|
+--------------------+--------+
|[[123, vv, pp, ll...|[vv, vv]|
+--------------------+--------+
```